Is there a notion of smooth sheaf which corresponds with smooth etale bundles?
It is well-known and quite useful that there is an equivalence of categories between sheaves of sets on a space $X$ and etale bundles over that space, meaning spaces $E$ and continuous maps $\pi:E\to X$ such that $E$ is covered by open sets $U$ where $\pi(U)$ is open and $\pi|_U:U\cong\pi(U)$ is a homeomorphism.
The correspondence goes by taking the sheaf of sections of the bundle, meaning the sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ which is defined on open $V\subseteq X$ as $\mathscr{F}(V):=\{\sigma:V\to E\text{ continuous }|\pi\circ\sigma=1_V:V\hookrightarrow X\}$.
I was thinking about the difference between the tangent bundle over a manifold and the associated etale bundle of the tangent sheaf earlier today. Here, the tangent sheaf on a smooth manifold $X$ is $\mathscr{T}_X:=\mathrm{Der}_{\Bbb R}(\mathscr{C}^\infty_X,\mathscr{C}^\infty_X)$ where $\mathscr{C}^\infty_X$ is understood as a sheaf, $\mathscr{C}^\infty_X(V)$ being the smooth functions $V\to\Bbb R$, $V$ any open. The stalks $\mathscr{T}_{X,x}$ admit natural evaluation maps to the tangent space of $X$ at a point $x$ but are not isomorphic, and the associated etale bundle of $\mathscr{T}_{X,x}$ is a rather messy thing (related question. However, in differential geometry we typically care about smooth sections of the tangent bundle $TX\to X$, not continuous as in the above.
This leads me to the question: is there a reasonable concept of a "smooth sheaf" such that there is an equivalence of categories, for a given smooth manifold $X$, between some notion of a 'smooth etale bundle' over $X$ and the smooth sheaves on $X$? Ideally via something analogous to taking smooth sections. It would be nice to understand the tangent bundle sheaf-theoretically...

I’m not sure exactly what you want, but the category of smooth vector bundles on a manifold is equivalent to the category of locally free sheaves of modules over the sheaf of smooth functions. The equivalence is given by taking smooth sections

@Exitpath have you a reference for the converse construction of the bundle from the sheaf?

I do not, but there should be plenty online. It should be fairly clear though; choose a trivializing open cover for your locally free sheaf. For each member $U$ of this open cover, the sections of the sheaf look like smooth maps $U \to \mathbb{R}^k$ for some fixed $k$, ie smooth sections of the trivial vector bundle of rank $k$. Now use isomorphisms on overlaps to construct your transition functions. Of course one needs to check that all possible choices make no difference in the end
